# What happens to std::async call if parent/main thread dies

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdthread, stdasync

If I am right, the std::async uses a new thread and calls the method in it. I was wondering what happens if the main thread or the parent thread dies. Does the thread controlling the async method dies as well.

Comment: If the main thread dies, all of the program's threads are interrupted and the program terminates. If the parent thread is not the main thread and it dies, nothing happens to the child thread I guess. I don't post this as an answer because I am not 100% sure and honestly I don't know all the details.

Comment: _"If I am right, the std::async uses a new thread and calls the method in it."_ you are actually wrong...

Comment: @K-ballo: not that i disagree with you, but i think it would be appropriate to accompany your judgement with some explanation, or your comment is not going to be very useful for the OP

Comment: @Andy Prowl: Agreed, but the explanation would be too long for a comment

Comment: Read about `std::async` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). Basically, with the default launch policy, the function may be launched in a new thread or it may be called synchronously when you get the result from the `std::future` depending on the implementation.

Comment: from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async:

"`f` may be started in a new thread or it may be run synchronously when the resulting `std::future` is queried for a value."

Comment: Technically a non-deferred function doesn't have to be run in a new thread, it just has to be _"as if"_ in a new thread. But IIUC in MS's implementation it might be run in a pre-existing thread, which I'm not sure is conforming because users can detect the difference by using `thread_local` variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no concept of a "parent" thread in C++, each thread is independent of the one that it was created by.  However, the `main` thread is special and if it returns from `main()` or calls `exit()` then the entire application is terminated even if other threads are still running.  Once that happens, the program has undefined behaviour if the still-running threads access any global variables or automatic objects that were on the main thread's stack, or use any standard library objects or call any function not permitted in signal handlers.

In short, do not let other threads run after `main` completes if you expect sensible results.

Comment: Can you cite the relevant standardese? I don't find anything pertaining to threads executing after `main()`exits (or I'm looking in the wrong places: neither 1.10 nor 3.30 contain anything).

Comment: Well obviously accessing any stack variables from `main` is undefined after `main` exits, the other cases are covered by 3.6.3 [basic.start.term]